# how can I manage user-dependent variables, that are valid on the whole domain ( Win Server 2003)

Tags: windows-server-2003

I am working on a system that needs a user-dependent variable, the user in on Windows XP and is connected to Windows Server 2003.

I cannot save this variable in the registry of the local machine under HKCU, because the users are likely to exchange their machines.

This variable must be accessible on the whole domain.

Do you have any idea of implementing this ? Are there WMI features that may help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing details you might want to look into [extending your Active Directory schema](http://www.setup32.com/network-administration/active-directory/modifying-active-directorys-schema.php).
An alternative (which isn't as scary and probably a bit safer)  is to use [ADAM.](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-5098967.html)